# Long table doesn't print out all items

Tags: longtable

I hope someone could help me with this, since I'm new to latex and I have very little latex knowledge which help me to solve this problem.
I've been struggling googling the answer for days already.

I've made changes in the code so you can run the code.

Problem Description:
I want to make a list of events as a PDF file. I use longtable to display it. 
But it doesn't print out correctly all the events. As you can see from the screenshot, that the list isn't complete printed out.

If I change the margin or the font size, it'll print out more, but still incomplete.

I've checked the log and it doesn't have the error message that I've expected.

Here is the Full Code that I use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\special{papersize=210mm,297mm}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}
\newcommand*{\SignatureAndDate}[1]{%
\par \hfill\makebox[2.0in][l]{Berlin, \today}%
\vspace*{15mm}%
\par \hfill\makebox[2.0in]{\hrulefill}%
\par \hfill\makebox[2.0in][c]{Unterschrift}%
}%
%%% --------------------------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%% Das Dokument
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}
\begin{landscape}
Fachgebiet Finalisierung Jahr 2014
\SignatureAndDate{Unterschrift}
\vspace*{20mm}
{\fontsize{6}{1em}\selectfont
\begin{longtable}{|p{40mm}|p{12mm}|p{20mm}|c|c|p{13mm}|c|c|p{23mm}|p{17mm}|c|c|c|}
\hline
Veranstaltung & LV-Nr & Dozent/in & FG-Leiter & Semester & LV-Typ & SWS & Teilnehmer                 & Studiengangsart & P/WP/W & Lehrauftrag & Titellehre & Status \\ \hline \endhead
\hline
Anlagen und Rohrnetzplanung     &       0330L052        &       Tham    &       Nein            &       WS      &       Uebung  &       2       &       1       &       Dipl    &       P               &       Nein    &       Nein &  Aktiv   \\ \hline
Anlagen und Rohrnetzplanung     &       0330L050        &       Tham    &       Nein    &       WS      &       Vorlesung       &       2       &       1       &       Dipl    &       P/WP    &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Ausbau Heiz- und Raumlufttechnik        &       0330L005        &       Mueller &       Nein    &       WS      &       Projekt &       2       &       1       &       MSc, Dipl       &       P       &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Ausbauseminar fuer das Fach Heiz- und Raumlufttechnik   &       0330L019        &       Mueller &       Nein    &       SS      &       Seminar &       4       &       1       &               MSc, Dipl       &       P/WP    &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Brandschutz     &       0330L040        &       Mueller &       Nein    &       SS      &       Vorlesung       &       2       &       1       &       MSc, Dipl       &       WP      &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Brandschutz     &       0330L041        &       Mueller &       Nein    &       SS      &       uebung  &       2       &       2       &       MSc, Dipl       &       P       &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Computergestuetztes Entwerfen und Berechnen von Gebaeuden       &       0330L080        &       MuellerWM       &       Nein    &       WS      &       Integrierte Veranstaltung       &       3       &       3       &       BSc, Dipl       &       WP      &       Nein    &                       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Heiztechnik IEnergiesysteme f. Gebaeude &       0330L001        &       Mueller &       Nein    &       SS      &       Vorlesung       &       2       &       4       &       BSc, Dipl       &       P/WP/W  &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Heiztechnik IIEnergiesysteme f. Gebaeude        &       0330L002        &       Kruehne &       Nein    &       WS      &       Vorlesung       &       2       &       1       &       MSc, Dipl       &       P       &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\         \hline
Hochbau- und Gebaeudekomponenten        &       0330L031        &       Seidel  &       Nein    &       WS      &       uebung  &       2       &       2       &       Dipl    &       WP      &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Hochbau- und Gebaeudekomponenten        &       0330L070        &       Seidel  &       Nein    &       WS      &       Vorlesung       &       2       &       2       &       Dipl    &       P/WP    &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Hochbau- und Gebaeudekomponenten        &       0330L031        &       Seidel  &       Nein    &       SS      &       uebung  &       2       &       1       &       Dipl    &       W       &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Hochbau- und Gebaeudekomponenten        &       0330L070        &       Seidel  &       Nein    &       SS      &       Vorlesung       &       2       &       1       &       Dipl    &       P/WP    &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Modul 6.3.1 Techn. Gebaeudeausruestung II       &       6392200L04      &       MuellerWM       &       Nein    &       SS      &       Projekt &       3       &       1       &       BSc     &       P/WP    &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Modul 6.3.1Techn. Gebaeudeausruestung I         &       ???     &       MuellerWM       &       Nein    &       WS      &       Vorlesung       &       2       &       1       &       BSc     &       P/WP    &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Modul 6.3.1Techn. Gebaeudeausruestung I         &       06382200L04     &       MuellerWM       &       Nein    &       WS      &       Vorlesung       &       2       &       1       &       BSc     &       P       &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\         \hline
Projekt Gebaeudetechnik Spezialisierung &       0330L011        &       Mueller &       Nein    &       WS      &       Projekt &       3       &       1       &       MSc, Dipl       &       W       &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Projekt Gebaeudetechnik Spezialisierung &       0330L011        &       Mueller &       Nein    &       SS      &       Projekt &       3       &       1       &       MSc, Dipl       &       P       &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Raumlufttechnik IEnergiesysteme f. Gebaeude     &       0330L003        &       Mueller &       Nein    &       SS      &       Vorlesung       &       2       &       1       &       BSc, Dipl       &       WP      &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\         \hline
Raumlufttechnik IIEnergiesysteme f. Gebaeude    &       0330L004        &       Kruehne &       Nein    &       WS      &       Vorlesung       &       2       &       1       &       MSc, Dipl       &       P/WP    &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\         \hline
Rechenuebung zu Heiz- und Raumlufttechnik IEnergiesysteme f. Gebaeude   &       0330L008        &       MuellerWM       &       Nein    &       SS      &       uebung  &       2       &       1       &       BSc, Dipl       &       W       &       Nein    &       Nein            &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Rechenuebung zu Heiz- und Raumlufttechnik IIEnergiesysteme f. Gebaeude  &       0330L007        &       MuellerWM       &       Nein    &       WS      &       uebung  &       2       &       1       &       MSc, Dipl       &       P/WP    &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline
Technische Grundlagen der Architektur  Gebaeudekunde Master- Modul 4    &       06382200L01     &       Mueller &       Nein    &       WS      &       Vorlesung       &       2       &       1       &       MSc     &       P/WP    &       Nein    &       Nein    &       Aktiv   \\ \hline

\end{longtable}
}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Please help me with this problem, or pls point what kind of mistakes that I've made.

Screenshot: (pages are manually rotated for convenience)
[image]

Comment: It printed fine for me. Perhaps it's your version of TeX distribution that is the issue, or you need to update one of the packages you're using in this document. 

this is the contents of the second page that printed:
http://i.imgur.com/CdHd5Fg.png

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Hmm, leave out the `\special` command, will be set by class ( and you have the papersize already set as class option, it’s BTW the default for KOMA-Script). Leave out package `anysize` and its command `\marginsize`, you have already loaded the competitive, but more recent package `geometry` with a different margin setting. Why don’t you invoke the font Helvetica with the package `helvet`? Not to speak from that you’ve already loaded the font family Latin Modern. But also with unchanged code I like Far Zin do not observe your problem.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to delete all help files, especially *.aux.